# How to simulate not reachable endpoint using wiremock?

Tags: wiremock

I would like to simulate endpoint eg. `/notReachable` that would fail in connecting.

How to achievie such mocking?

Answer (score 3):

Maybe something like this, found on wiremock site [wiremock faults](http://wiremock.org/docs/simulating-faults/)

```
stubFor(get(urlEqualTo("/fault"))
    .willReturn(aResponse().withFault(Fault.MALFORMED_RESPONSE_CHUNK)));
```